# How can we resolve this issue?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TulaO.png)

I have an old project and when I changed the Gradle plugin version and the Gradle version, it results in build errors... I also posted the screenshot.

How we can solve this error?  How we can create a successful build.  I am using Kotlin version 1.5.31.

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you are upgrading the Gradle plugin version, you should double check the documentation concerning the field.  When I search for it, I find that the documentation says that the field name was deprecated in favor of `checkReleaseBuilds`.  So, you would likely have to change your grade file to reflect the new parameter name.

https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.3/com/android/build/api/dsl/LintOptions#isCheckReleaseBuilds()

> isCheckReleaseBuilds

> var isCheckReleaseBuilds: Boolean
> This property is deprecated.
> Moved to lint.checkReleaseBuilds

Answer (score 0):

To change the default Gradle location used when creating a new project in Android Studio, you can configure the Gradle settings in Android Studio. Here are the steps to do that:

1. Open Android Studio.
2. Click on "File" in the top menu bar.
3. Go to "Settings" (or "Preferences" on macOS).
4. In the Settings/Preferences dialog, expand the "Build, Execution, Deployment" category.
5. Select "Build Tools" and then choose "Gradle."
6. In the "Gradle" settings, you'll find an option for "Use gradle from." By default, it's set to "wrapper." Change it to "Specified location."
7. Next to the "Specified location" option, you can browse and set the path to your preferred Gradle distribution. In your case, you should set it to the desired Gradle location, like 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr'.
8. Click "Apply" and then "OK" to save the changes.

After making these changes, Android Studio will use the specified Gradle location as the default for new projects you create. This way, you can ensure that the Gradle distribution you want is consistently used in your projects.